# How to read specific cells from excel data into Pyomo

Tags: excel, pyomo

Greetings and many thanks for your time in advance.

Can someone please point out the *official* (not custom-made packages and libraries from other devs) way of reading excel data into Pyomo from specific sheets and ranges of cells, assigning them to model.X components?

Cheers,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with the Pyomo data portal but it is not well-documented. See the files named ABCD7.* [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/examples/doc/pyomobook/data-abstract-ch). I think a better approach would be to read the excel file into Python using something like [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) and then construct your Pyomo model.